# triming <br> tag in javascript using regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, trim

I have a regex that I wanted to trim the <br> of a variable

```
str1.replace(/^&lt;br&gt;|&lt;br&gt;$/g,'');
```

example i want to trim a string something like this

```
var str1 = "<br>hooray!<br>";
```

and i want it to be like this

```
var str = "hooray!";
```

but it seems not to be working...

what is the correct regex for removing the first and last <br> tag?

Comment: Please give some sample input strings and expected output for corresponding input string

Comment: Assuming you've already tried `/^<br>|<br>$/g`?

Comment: yes i tried it... it doesn't work...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
str1.replace(/(^<br>|<br>$)/g,"");
```

Demo on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WBfxm/)

Comment: What do we do if we want to also remove <br/>

Comment: @DustinPoissant to also remove `<br/>`, use this regular expression: `/(^<br\/?>|<br\/?>$)/g`. This checks for an optional slash.

Comment: And optional space for ``<br />`` would look like this ``/(^<br\s?\/?>|<br\s?\/?>$)/g`` I am guessing but im not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var mystring = '<br>hooray!<br>';
var find = "<br>"; 
var regex = new RegExp(find, "g"); 
var result = mystring.replace(regex, "");
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gE5tg/)

Answer (score 0):

I think `br` tag is usually written as `<br/>` so you  can use regex like `<br[ ]?/>;`

If you want to cover `br` tag which is written as `<br> </br>`then you have to use `<br>[\s\S]*?<br[ ]?/>`

**After question is edited**

for input like `<br>hooray!<br>`
 this, you can use just `<br>` and replace all matches with blank

Comment: is my regex for trimming br's is correct? to remove the first and last one

Comment: @Mahan, your regex will only work for <br> tags which are at either start of line or at the end of line. You can use simple <br> tag to remove all <br> occurring anywhere in input string

Comment: @Mahan, better idea is to use string replace instead of using regex because I dont see any advantage of using regex in your case. If you want to use some special chars like * or ? or backtracking then you can go with regex, otherwise simple string replacement will be efficient and sufficient.

Comment: You can't use `&lt;` in regular expressions, because that matches exactly `&lt;` -- it doesn't transliterate it to `<`. And @Mahan doesn't mention `<br>` in the middle of the text, only at the beginning and end.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, &lt; replaced with <

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**
`(?im)(^<br[\s/]*>|<br[\s/]*>$)`

**JavaScript Code:**

`result = subject.replace(/(?:(?:^<br[\s\/]*>)|(?:<br[\s\/]*>$))/mg, "");`

Answer (score 0):

This appeared to work for me and handle cases where the break tag was strangely encoded...

```
var newData = data.replace(/&lt;br ?\/\>|&lt;br ?\/&rt;|\<br ?\/\>/g, "\n");
```